# how to enable wifi adb on Intellij IDEA in 2022

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I noticed that I'm unable to pair a device via wifi in intellij idea but can with android studio following these directions: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi-android-11+. Is there some official way to enable this with Intellij?

Comment: What IntelliJ IDEA version do you use? `Help | About` Do you see any errors after clicking on "Pair Devices Using Wi-Fi"?

Comment: hi. the option doesn't exist at all on intellij 2022.1.4 on macos

Comment: Please check if the problem reproduces in the 2022.2.3 build from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download

Comment: @EgorKlepikov this fixed it but now I'm having a different issue where the wifi connect feature isn't consistent and a way to get it to actually connect is to disable wifi debugging on my android device as well as clear all paired devices and then retry. Thank you.